# Error while installing the maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to Eclipse. I was installing Maven plugin in Eclipse Helios and I have gone through all the answers from stack but still I was not able to solve it. I used

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3
```

this link in the `Eclipse -> Help > Install New software`. Still I am getting bellow error. Can any one help me ?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e connector for the Maven Dependency Plugin 0.0.4.201410161303 (com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.feature.feature.group 0.0.4.201410161303)
  Missing requirement: m2e connector for Maven Dependency Plugin 0.0.4.201410161303 (com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core 0.0.4.201410161303) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.4.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for the Maven Dependency Plugin 0.0.4.201410161303 (com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.feature.feature.group 0.0.4.201410161303)
    To: com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core [0.0.4.201410161303]
```

Comment: Why dont you use Eclipse Marketplace?

Comment: Why are you running a seven year old version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Like [Sudha Velan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2783746/sudha-velan) said, you try the eclipse marketplace(Help -> Eclipse Marketplace).

I prefer downloading the binary files from the [maven homepage](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).